# Using mod_rewrite to remove .php extension from requests

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have an account with godaddy, and I am trying to get my website's urls to leave out the .php extension at the end of the path by doing some mod_rewrite scripting, but my script is not working. Here it is:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)/$ $1.php
```

If there is anything that I haven't included or any errors in that script please help me figure it out.

I have looked through different similar posts regarding this issue, but none were gave me any answers that helped me resolve this issue.

Comment: What exact input URL are you testing?  Your `RewriteRule` expects a trailing `/`

Comment: A simple url, for instance foo.com/index.php would become foo.com/index

Comment: That's now how mod_rewrite works. It won't actively change a request to /index.php into /index unless you do a lot more work (as in Justin's answer below). Normally it is used to silently change `/index` into `/index.php`, which is what you have above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you enable `MultiViews` option (apache content negotiation) you will be able to reach both `/page` and `/page.php`

```
Options +MultiViews
```

But if you want **only** `/page` (and redirect `/page.php` to `/page`) you can do it this way

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/([^/]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule . /%1? [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1.php [L]
```

Comment: I'm very new at working with server administration and I tried using your script in my .htaccess file. It didn't end up working. Could it be that the .htaccess file is placed in the wrong directory(I have it in the root of the website)? Also, are there any good online resources that go through how to properly use mod_rewrite?

Comment: I'm sorry, i forgot a slash that changes everything. I tested it and it's working, you can try again with my edited code